# Key press recognition within while loops. Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, pygame

I am attempting to program a simple dialogue box in a game. I am using a while loop for the overall game loop. and a while loop within this loop activated by the player pressing space. I want the player to press space(speech() function) to enter the second while loop and press A (speech_end()) to exit this loop. However, speech_end does not work within this second loop unless I am already holding the A. I have tested it outside of this loop and it works fine. Any help is appreciated.

```
#Classes
class Bertha(object):

    image = pygame.image.load("bertha.png")

    def __init__(self, berthax, berthay, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()


        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = berthax
        self.rect.y = berthay

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)



class Player(object):

    # one image for all instances
    image = pygame.image.load('player.png')

    def __init__(self, playerx, playery, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        # every instance can have own image
        #self.image = pygame.image.load('test.jpg')

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = playerx
        self.rect.y = playery


#moving with Arrow keys
    def movement(self):

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            self.dist_x = 0
            self.dist_y = 0
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.dist_x += 5
                if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                    self.dist_y -= 5
                elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                    self.dist_y += 5

            elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.dist_x -= 5
                if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                    self.dist_y -= 5
                elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                    self.dist_y += 5

            elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.dist_y -= 5
                if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                    self.dist_x += 5
                elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    self.dist_x -= 5

            elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.dist_y += 5
                if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                    self.dist_x += 5
                elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    self.dist_x -= 5




#------------Confirming player position--------------


        self.rect.x += self.dist_x
        self.rect.y += self.dist_y


    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)





# --------Talking to another character----------------



def speech():

    keys1 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    global talking
    if keys1[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        talking = 1



def speech_end():

    keys2 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    global talking
    if keys2[pygame.K_a]:
        talking = 2
        print("speech_end")










# ----- Bertha Messages



def bertha_text(screen, font):

    text = font.render("spacebar worked!", True, BLACK)

    text_rect = text.get_rect()

    text_rect.center = (400, 20)

    screen.blit(text, text_rect)

    pygame.display.update()






# - other -

font = pygame.font.SysFont("moon_get-Heavy.ttf", 40)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

playerx = 100
playery = 100

berthax = 400
berthay = 400


player_one = (Player(playerx, playery, screen))
bertha_npc = (Bertha(berthax, berthay, screen))




talking = 0

# - mainloop -


running = True


while running:

    talking = 0


    screen.blit(map_img, (0, 0))

#Player


    player_one.movement()
    player_one.draw(screen)



#Bertha
    bertha_npc.draw(screen)
#------Show the text------


    speech()

    while talking == 1:

        bertha_text(screen, font)
        speech_end()

        print(talking)

        if talking == 2:

            print("talking == False")
            talking -= 2
            break





#UPDATE

    pygame.display.update()
        # - FPS -
    clock.tick(60)



# - end -

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Please read the [mcve page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We like concise and executable examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the events in the inner while loop. Either call [`pygame.event.pump()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or use one of the other event functions, for example `for event in pygame.event.get():`.

Also, call `clock.tick(60)` in the inner loop as well.

```
while talking == 1:
    pygame.event.pump()
    bertha_text(screen, font)
    speech_end()

    print(talking)

    if talking == 2:
        print("talking == False")
        talking -= 2
        break

    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: BTW, better remove the event loop (`for event in pygame.event.get():`) from your player class and insert it in the main while loop. When your code works correctly, you can post it (a complete, runnable version) on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pygame to get some refactoring tips.

Comment: Apologies for the long winded post I figured more detail was better than less. I will keep in mind for next time.

Comment: You could (or should) still try to improve the question for other reviewers or people with the same problem. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Gotcha will do, tomorrow. Thanks!